# How can I use my .conll file from nlp parser for feature selection

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I have an outputted .conll format file from Malt Parser, which is using the engmalt.linear-1.7.mco training model. My original input was a large text file of sentences. How can I use this file for feature selection?

I am using python with Scikit-learn (currently using tfidf bag of words to select features). However, I want to utilize nlp, by for example, only searching for adjectives. How can I do this with a conll file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of a parser in the CoNLL-X format provides a separate column for the part-of-speech tags. For example, if you parse the sentence

> "I want to select adjectives only, and disregard other tags."

the output might be as follows:

```
1   I           _   PRP PRP _   2   nsubj   _   _
2   want        _   VB  VBP _   0   null    _   _
3   to          _   TO  TO  _   4   aux _   _
4   select      _   VB  VB  _   2   xcomp   _   _
5   adjectives  _   NN  NNS _   4   dobj    _   _
6   only        _   RB  RB  _   4   advmod  _   _
7   ,           _   ,   ,   _   2   punct   _   _
8   and         _   CC  CC  _   2   cc  _   _
9   disregard   _   VB  VB  _   2   conj    _   _
10  other       _   JJ  JJ  _   11  amod    _   _
11  tags        _   NN  NNS _   9   dobj    _   _
12  .           _   .   .   _   2   punct   _   _
```

Columns 4 and 5 show the coarse- and fine-grained part-of-speech tags, respectively. If you only want to select adjectives, you need to just pick words that have `JJ` as their coarse-tag in column 4.

Once you have selected the specific words according to whatever your selection criteria is, you can proceed to construct the vectors in the usual way.

**P.S.** I assumed your query was mostly to do with the CoNLL format, and not about how to extract the adjectives (which, of course, can be done by tab-splitting rows or regex matching -- there are several questions and answers on SO pertaining to the pythonic ways of doing those).

Comment: I see, I suppose there is no way to obtain things like noun phrases without looking at 2 rows together and evaluating their parts of speech?

Comment: If you want phrasal features, then trying to use dependency parse is not the right way to go. It can, of course, be done, but there are simpler ways (and extracting phrases from dependency parse trees should really be a separate question on its own). You should look at a phrase-chunker or a constituency parser (usually just called "parser").